# play channels from dvb with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, television, dvb

How can we play or process a tv channel with `ffplay, ffmpeg` from a tuner on tv card on linux. I am able to play with vlc when I tune a tuner wtih `szap` with command `szap-s2 "channel" -a 0 -H` . However, I could not achieve this with ffmpeg. I also want to play multiple channels at same time on one transponder.

Comment: The O.P. of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107625/how-can-i-concatenate-atsc-streams-from-dvb-card/25142276#25142276) question describes his solution in his question: it might help

Comment: "I also want to play multiple channels at same time on one transponder." Have you found a solution to this already?

Comment: Hi scaryguy, there are tools streaming tv channels from tv cards through some urls. I am able to any processes using this streaming urls. [tvheadend](https://tvheadend.org/projects/tvheadend/wiki/Download/2) is one of this streaming tools which reads from tvcards and publish tv channels on some urls. In order to play multiple channels you will just call another script like `ffmpeg localhost:9981/..` . If they are on same transponder or there is another empty transponder there will be no problem.

Comment: apparently ffmpeg can receive from a properly "pre configured" video4linux dvb tuning device: https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-December/003955.html https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-and-Audio-grabbing

Comment: Thank you for your answers, however it has been long time I asked this question so I am not able to test your recommendations. Somebody may test and write results here.